# For what versions of iPhone and iPad is the Battery Health available?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, battery, ipados

I found out that the Battery Health Option is available on iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch from
iOS 11.3 and later.

> [With iOS 11.3 and later, you can see your battery health and if a battery needs to be replaced](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201264)

But I could see what versions of iPhone, iPad and iPod it includes?

Also, iOS no longer runs on iPads - but iPadOS, so does that imply that iPad doesn't have an Battery Health Option anymore or maybe iPad never did?

Comment: As iPad OS was released concurrently with iOS 13, it would be fair to assume any iDevice that runs iOS 11.3 or later can see the Battery Health data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's online documentation states (my emphasis in **bold**):

> For **iPhone 6 and later**, iOS 11.3 and later add new features to show battery health and recommend if a battery needs to be replaced. These can be found in Settings > Battery > Battery Health.

I found this info here on Apple's Support website: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208387